# Max Mantissa $2^{bits}-1$

Tags: floating-point

if we look at a $5$ bit mantissa, the max value will be $11111$ which is $2^5-1$, Why is it in the form of $2^{bits}-1$ is it a combinatorial explanation?

Comment: each bit has $2$ possibilities, $0$ or $1$, so there are $2^5$ possibilities for $5$-bit values, but the first $5$-bit value is $0$, so subtract $1$ to get the max value

Comment: @J.W.Tanner why the first $5$-bit value is $0$? it all ones

Comment: meaning among the $2^5$ possible $5$-bit values ($00000, 00001, 00010, 00011,$ etc.) the first value is $0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I see, why we have to remove it? as it can not be a max?

Comment: I was listing the possibilities in order of value

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I understood, what I do not get is why we have to remove the possibility of getting the value zero?

Comment: Count $0$ as the first, so $11111$ is the last (the 32nd); $m-1$ is the $m$-th; so the max value is $2^5-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at unsigned binary integers, the smallest in $n$ bits is $00000$ with $n$ zeros and the highest is $11111$ with $n$ ones.  It is just like in base $10$ where the largest number with $n$ digits is all $9$s.  Then to see that this equals $2^n-1,$ note that the bits are successively $2^0+2^1+2^2+\ldots +2^{n-1}$.  The sum of this geometric series is $2^n-1$